# Instruction: SetAuthority Error: owner does not match

Tags: solana, metaplex, anchor-solana, solana-program-library

I get this error when trying to mint master edition nft using CPI of the metaplex program

```
Program log: Setting mint authority
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]
   Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority
   Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1929 of 116474 compute units
   Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success
   Program log: Setting freeze authority
   Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]
   Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority
   Program log: Error: owner does not match
   Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1816 of 111354 compute units
   Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0x4
   Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 34531 of 144069 compute units
```

this is the code where the error pops up specifically at the create master edition invoking part

```
let master_edition_infos = vec![
           ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
           ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
           ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
           ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
           ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
           ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
           ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
           ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
           ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
       ];

invoke(
           &create_master_edition_v3(
               ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
               ctx.accounts.master_edition.key(),
               ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
               ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
               ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
               ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
               ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
               Some(0),
           ),
           master_edition_infos.as_slice(),
       )?;
```

this is the data im passing thru the client side

```
(await program.rpc.mintTicket({
          accounts: {
            mintAuthority: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
            eventAccount: eventPDA,
            mint: mintKey.publicKey,
            tokenAccount: NftTokenAccount,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            metadata: metadataAddress,
            tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
            payer: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            masterEdition: masterEdition,
          },
        }));
```

these are the accounts/pubkeys

```
Program Id: Crvo7H5Qupi7pD63wyyXfoPbzAkU9Hbqwno7xTrXLbKo
Event PDA:  4U1p28aYRULrkfWgUrspqPEpyauXEQRY2pAyBYhXSdhy
NFT Account:  BBqs3FzBk74FGJtQ2XQbz8ZiDq9iaTBL78obSL6xhuvq
Parsed account:3XAzUULWFYkKjRGAF9LXdY21XPsvRBNSadNWXd6qCsXTSagKJVQc9U8wziuj483yy3y1JAKkzQuyhZj4G2cjdM2a
Mint key:  7hormNKw6RcX2jEBjLLdLdzb6JvHK7oN3PymDjxdbFdh
User:  7CtWnYdTNBb3P9eViqSZKUekjcKnMcaasSMC7NbTVKuE
Metadata address:  Envsbupi5iaCaoZ2eFAsr1ZiM1qUZCB1tiZVygY3GrpS
MasterEdition:  AX4VN8LN5B8xoHkf6kbLMTmF5RBiKcfi2QJt6fnCiJCL
```

[image: explorerpic]
And I think the issue is to do with the fact that the mint address([explorer_link](https://explorer.solana.com/address/7hormNKw6RcX2jEBjLLdLdzb6JvHK7oN3PymDjxdbFdh?cluster=devnet)) has mint authority set to the user but update authority is not the user although im not sure and would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed this issue it was my mistake when i ran this function on the client side i gave it the wrong key for freeze authority

```
createInitializeMintInstruction(
          mintKey.publicKey,
          0,
          program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
          program.provider.wallet.publicKey // works now but before was mintKey.publicKey
        ),
```

i accidentaly added mint key as freeze authority instead of users key